# Interop Exception when looking at cell data to perform formatting

Tags: c#, exception, excel-interop, comexception

I have a small application that queries a DB on a networked Windows Server running SQL Server and outputs the data to an Excel file. I am working on formatting the excel file how I need and I'm running into an exception I've never seen when trying to view the data in the cells. Here is my code:

```
            xlWorkSheet.Activate();
            xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1;
            xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1;
            xlWorkSheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;
            xlWorkSheet.Columns.AutoFit();
            for (i = 0; i <= xlWorkSheet.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if(xlWorkSheet.Cells[i,5].Value2 == "PAST DUE")
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 5].Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
                }
            }
```

This is the exception I'm receiving:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'

All other applications I've written that look at cell data have never had any problem with this same type of usage.

The Exception happens at this line:

```
if(xlWorkSheet.Cells[i,5].Value2 == "PAST DUE")
```

Comment: Cell[] indices start at 1, not 0.

Comment: Ah yes thank you, I was thrown off by that silliness. Is there a major reason why Excel Interop does this?

Comment: Sure, the "native" programming language for Excel is VBA.  Basic programmers traditionally liked starting to count at 1.  An implementation detail that cannot be easily hidden, too expensive.